# Cómo cargar una lista con el resultado de un queryset

Tags: python, django

Tengo el resultado de un queryset (`q = facturas.objects.all()`) y quiero cargar una lista o diccionario con el número de la factura más otros valores calulados.
Ej:

Tengo mis facturas y para cada registro quiero obtener el total (que ya lo tengo), más el importe ya abonado y saldo. Luego espero recorrer el diccionario o lista y cargar mi template.

```
{% for factura in listado%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ factura.numero }}</td>                                       
        // aqui recorreria la lista o diccionario y cargaria para cada factura los valores
        // que correspondan     
    <tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda para poder armar lo que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es por cada factura hacer los calculos respectivos y crear un lista de diccionarios que puedas renderizar en tu template

Los pasos que te recomendaría son los siguientes.

1. En el view, obtener todas las facturas
2. Luego, iterar sobre cada factura para calcular los valores que necesites o ejecutar las acciones pertinentes segun sea el caso
3. Crear un dict que almacene la información procesada y añadirlo a una lista para que puedas renderizarla en tu template

Quedando algo como esto:

```
def facturas(request):
    facturas = Facturas.objects.all()

    detalles_facturas = []
    for factura in facturas:
        total_factura = metodo_para_calcular_total_de_la_factura(factura)
        # o pudiera ser un metodo de la clase: factura.metodo_para_calcular_total_de_la_factura()

        saldo = metodo_para_calcular_saldo_de_la_factura(factura)
        otra_cosa = metodo_para_calcular_otra_cosa_de_la_factura(factura)

        # creas un dict que apendaras a la lista detalles_facturas
        detalles_factura = {
            "factura": factura,
            "total_factura": total_factura,
            "saldo": saldo,
            "otra_cosa": otra_cosa,
        }
        detalles_facturas.append(detalles_factura)

        # pudieras hacer la asignacion de valores directamente al crear el dicsin necesidad de crear una variable por cada valor a calcular, trato de hacerlo lo mas ilustrativo posible

        return render(request, 'facturas.html', locals())
```

Y en tu template puedes mostrar los resultados de la siguiente forma

```
{% for detalles in detalles_facturas %}
    <tr>
        <td>Factura numero: {{ detalles.factura.numero }}</td>
        <td>Total: {{detalles.total_factura}}</td>
        <td>Saldo: {{detalles.saldo}}</td>
        <td>Otra cosa: {{detalles.otra_cosa}}</td>
    <tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar el queryset directamente a la plantilla sin problemas para después iterar sobre él. No es necesario que lo evalúes antes de enviarlo a la plantilla.

**EDIT:**
Puedes pasar más datos aparte del queryset a la plantilla indicándolo como un diccionario

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from tu_app.models import Facturas

def detail(request):
    queryset = Facturas.objects.all()
    contexto = {
        'facturas': queryset, 
        'otro_parametro': contenido, 
        ...
    }
    return render(request, 'facturas.html', contexto)
```

Comment: Tengo entendido por lo leído en otras respuestas que la lógica debería estar toda en la view no en el template y yo necesito pasar mas datos aparte de los obtenidos en el queryset.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta.